# MinGW on Windows: cmake arguments to find wxWidgets?

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

Similar questions already exist but I haven't found an answer that works.

I need to build a wxWidgets project in Windows using MinGW, I would like to use the cmake command from the command line (I installed mingw, cmake and bash using chocolatey)

I would like to avoid compiling wxWidgets so I am using the pre-built binaries `MinGW-w64 10.2` (`Headers` + `Dev x64` + `Release x64`), I unpack them to `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.5`

I've tried a number of combinations of arguments for cmake but haven't found one that works on the first run, I say first run because I've found one that works on the second:

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" \
     -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/ \
     -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/
```

I am not a cmake expert but I imagine that by specifying these arguments in the first run they are cached and in the second run they are used, bypassing the search.

What I would like to know is what arguments I have to give to get them to be found correctly, `_CONFIGURATION`, `_ROOT_DIR`, `_LIBRARIES`, `_INCLUDE_DIRS` don't seem to have any effect.

↓ **edit** ↓

`CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Test)
set(wxWidgets_USE_LIBS)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED) 
if(wxWidgets_FOUND)
    include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
    add_executable(MyTest WIN32 main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(MyTest ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
else(wxWidgets_FOUND)
    message("wxWidgets not found!")
endif(wxWidgets_FOUND)
```

command line used:

```
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/ -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/  -DwxWidgets_wxrc_EXECUTABLE=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/wxrc.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DwxWidgets_LIBRARIES=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/ -DwxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5/include/
```

first run:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS core base) 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Alex/Documents/Progetti/wx-test/build
wxWidgets not found!
```

second run:

```
-- Found wxWidgets: debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxmsw31ud_core.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxmsw31u_core.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxbase31ud.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxbase31u.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxbase31ud_net.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxbase31u_net.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxpngd.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxpng.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxtiffd.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxtiff.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxjpegd.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxjpeg.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxzlibd.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxzlib.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxregexud.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxregexu.a;debug;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxexpatd.a;optimized;C:/wxWidgets-3.1.5/lib/gcc1020_x64_dll/libwxexpat.a;winmm;comctl32;uuid;oleacc;uxtheme;rpcrt4;shlwapi;version;wsock32 (found version "3.1.5") found components: core base net png tiff jpeg zlib regex expat 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Alex/Documents/Progetti/wx-test/build
```

if I use `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)`:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:1025 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
```

Comment: You forgot to show the **error message**. "I say first run because I've found one that works on the second" - this could point to some problems with your **code**, which you didn't provide.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the error is a generic message, something like: wxWidgets not found (wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS). I tried to set the two variables but got the same result, no success.

Comment: "the error is a generic message..." - Please, post the **exact error message**: in many cases it actually matters. About importance of the exact error message see also that [question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: The output on the first run doesn't correspond to your code: 1. The output "Configuring done" means that configuration is successful, but your code uses REQUIRED keyword for `find_package`, which means "fail configuration if the package is not found". 2. The line "Build files have been written to ..." should be **the last** in the CMake output. So following "wxWidgets not found!" shouldn't be there (output of the `message` command is printed immediately during the configuration). It smells like you use complex structure of your project, probably with inner ones.It is not reflected in the code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I just removed REQUIRED, on Windows 2>&1 isn't capturing all the output so I did some copy paste. The project is a simple hello world, I'm just testing the environment right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Process Monitor` I noticed that `FindwxWidgets.cmake` looks for libraries in `gcc_dll/` (not `gcc2010_x64_dll/`), once the directory was renamed `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=/c/wxWidgets-3.1.5` was enough to find the directory on the first run.